# MATLAB Database Searching

Tags: database, matlab, search

I have to compare certain stored images (saved in .dat format) in my MATLAB Fingerprint Recognition System. Now, I can perform 1:1 matching, however, it isn't feasible for a relatively larger database of, say, 300 employees. 
Any suggestions for what I could do?

(a) Something like, adding the address of where the complete database is stored

(b) Functions to employ best possible matching algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = [';@3EA4:aei7]ced.CFHE;4\T>*Y>,dL0,HOQQMJLJE9PX[[Q.ZF.\JTCA1dd'
     '<A;FB:;bfj8^df//DGIF<5]UF+ZH-eM>-IorRPNMPIE-Y\\R8[I8]SUDW2e+'
     '=4BGC;<cgk9_e00DEOJG=6^VG,[I.fN?5jpsSQPNQPF.Z,]S9`S9cTWVX:+,'
     ':5CHD<=4hlh`f11EFPKHA7&WH-\J/gOC?kqtTRRORQJ8--^TB+T=dWYWY;,_'
     ';6D3E=>7imiag2IFOQLID8''XI.]K0"PD@l32UZhP//P988_WC,U>+Z^Y\<2`'
     '<82BF>?8jnjbhLJGPRMJE9/YJ/`L1#QMC$;;V[iv09QE99,XD.YB,[_\]=3a'
     '>9;CG?@9kokc2MKHQSOKF:0ZL0aM2$RNG%AAW\jw9E.FEE-_G8aG.d`]_W5+'
     '?:CDH@A:lpld3NLIRTPLG=1[M1bN3%SOH4BBX]kx:J9LLL8`H9bJ/+d_dX6,'
     '@;DEIAB;mqmePOMJSUQMJ>2\N2cO4&TPP@HCY^lyDKEMMN9+I@+S8,+deY7^'
     '8@EFJBC<4rnfQPNPTVRNKB3]O3dP5''UQQCIDZ_mzEPFNNOE,RA,T9/,++\8_'
     '9A2G3CD=544gRQPQUWUOLE4^P4"Q6(VRRIJE[`n{KQKOOPK-SE.W:F/,,]Z+'
     ':BDH4DE>655hSRQRVXVPMF5_Q5#R>)eSSJKF\ao0L.L-WUL.VF8XCH001_[,'
     ';3EI<EO?766iTSRSWYWQNG6$R6''S?*fTTlLQ]bp1M/P.XVP8[H9]DIDA=`\]'
     '?4D3=FP@877jUTSTXZXROK7%S7(TF+gUUmMR^cq:N9Q8YZQ9_I>cIJEB>d_^'
     '@5E@>GQA98b3VUTUY*YSPL8&T>)UI,hVhnNS_dr;PE.9Z[RCaR?+JTFC?e`+'
     '79FA?HRB:9c4WVUVZ+ZWQM=,WG*VJ-"gi4OT`es<QL9E[\TD+SA,SWUVW+d,'
     '8:3B@JSX;:dVXWVW[,[XRN>-XH+bK.#hj@PUvftDRMEF,]UH,UB.TYVWX,e\'
     '9;ECAKTY<;eWYXWX\:)YSOE.YI,cL/$ikCqV1guE/PFL-^XI-YG/WZWXY1+]'
     ':AFDBLUZ=<fXZYXY,;*ZTPF/ZJ-dM0%j#Jrt2hxH0QKM8,YJ.ZI8[^YY\2,,'
     ';B3ECMV[>jgY[ZYZ-<7[XQG0[K.eN1&"$K2u:iyO9.PN9-_K8aJ9\_]\]82['
     '?CEFDNW\?khZ\[Z[==8\YRH1\M/!O2''#%m31Bw0PE/QXE8+R9bS;da^]_93\'
     '@2FGEOX]ali[]\[\>>9(ZSL2]N0"P3($&n;2Cx1QN9--L9,SA+T<+d__`:4,'
     'A3GHFPY^bmj\^]\]??:)[TM3^O1%Q4)%''oA:D0:0OE.8ME-TE,XB,+`da;5['
     '643IGQZ_cnk]_^]^@@;5\UN4_P2&R6*&(3B;E1<1PN99NL8WF.^C/,a+bY6,'
     '7:F3HR[`dol^`_^_AA<6]VO5`Q3''S>+'');CBF:=:QOEEOO9_G8aH6/d,cZ[Y'
     '8;G4IS\aep4_a`_-BD=7''XP6aR4(T?,(5@DCHCC;RPFLPPD`H9bJ70+0d\\Z'
     '9BH>JT^bf45`ba`.CE@8(YQ7#S5)UD-)?AEDIDDD/QKMVQJ+S?cSDF,1e]a,'
     ':C3?K4_cg5[acbaADFA92ZR8$T6*VE.*@JFEJEEE0.NNWTK,U@+TEG0?+_bX'
     ';2D@L9`dh6\bdcbBEGD:3[S=)U7+cK/+CKGFLIKI9/OWZUL-VA,WIHB@,`cY'];
i = double(c(:)-32);
j = cumsum(diff([0; i])<=0) + 1;
S = sparse(i,j,1)';
spy(S)
```